# problem in spring boot test by use @Import

Tags: maven, junit, spring-boot-test

I work with spring boot test and use junit4. I want use @Import for TestConfiguration classes in test class. But when i run maven test get this exception:
[main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.service.OrchestratedServiceTest], using SpringBootContextLoader